# How to get started with XCode Project from Bitbucket

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a new member in my team joining today. We have a new system that has been set up for the first time with fresh installation of XCode.

we are trying to fetch the master from `bitbucket` however it is taking too long to fetch the file from master and is stuck at verifying credentials. I have tried the same on my system (which is in sync with the master) and was able to download the code in about 5 mins.

Basically, I have 2 concerns

1. Since its first time is the system taking time for verifying
   credentials ?
2. Is it something I am missing like configuring git on
       the system or something like that?

I just want to download the project using `git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/username_ios.git` and get started.

Comment: What happens if you abort the download and then try it again?

Comment: @Feldur its being downloaded on other system, but not on new one

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question. On the system where it was failing, if you abort what it's doing and then restart does it continue to fail?

Comment: Well, on the new system it hangs at verifying credentials, where as on the old one, the clone gets downloaded properly.

Comment: Can't explain that; pragmatically, I'd copy the dmg file from one machine to the other and move on

Comment: @Feldur, I think you have misunderstood the question.  I wish to download the bitbucket clone, on the new system that has xcode installed.

Comment: Are you trying to understand what's wrong, or get the code and do some work? If it's the former, I don't know what to tell you. If the latter, then copy the code from machine that can get it and move on

Comment: Its the former. Anyways thanks a lot for your valuable time